# ResultSet caching using oracle 12c release 2

Tags: java, oracle

i am trying to fetch a results from ResultSet Cache using JDBC API. I am using an Oracle 12c R2 database (ojdbc8.jar).

I made the following configurations to support the same as follows:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET CLIENT_RESULT_CACHE_SIZE=1G SCOPE=SPFILE
ALTER SYSTEM SET CLIENT_RESULT_CACHE_LAG=1000 SCOPE=SPFILE
```

Restarted database using SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE and STARTUP command.

Connect to the schema and execute following command,

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME RESULT_CACHE(MODE FORCE)
```

The tester program I developed:

```
public class OracleResultsetCacheDemo {
Connection con = null;  
public static void main(String[] args) {         
    OracleResultsetCacheDemo tester = new OracleResultsetCacheDemo();
    tester.performOperation();
        }

public void performOperation() {
                try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "pass");

                String query = "select /*+RESULTSET_CACHE*/ * from <table_name>";
    System.out.println("Default : "+((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)con).getImplicitCachingEnabled());           ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)con).setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);            ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)con).setStatementCacheSize(10);  System.out.println("After setting manually: "((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)con).getImplicitCachingEnabled());

    PreparedStatement stm;
    OracleResultSet rs;

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         stm = con.prepareStatement(query);
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          rs = (OracleResultSet) stm.executeQuery();
         System.out.println("isFromResultSetCache:"+rs.isFromResultSetCache() );  
         while (rs.next()) {
             //do somthing
         }
         rs.close();
         stm.close();
         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long finalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(getTimeStamp(finalTime));
        }             
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public String getTimeStamp(long finalTime) {

    long millis = finalTime % 1000;
    long second = (finalTime / 1000) % 60;
    long minute = (finalTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    long hour = (finalTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

    String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%d", hour, minute, second, millis);
return time;
}}
```

In the for in the above code, I try to fetch the result set by executing query and then check whether the rs.isFromResultSetCache is true.

For the first time, the isFromResultSetCache is false as the resultSet is fetched for the first time. 
But it should have returned as true in the next iteration as per ResultSet Caching.

I am unable to figure out the problem here. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the hints in the query for caching the resultset. Can you review the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/boost-the-java-apps-performance-through-client-side-resultset-cache) for more details?

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to mention here. i have already added this hint in my code. (select   /*+ RESULT_CACHE*/   TDIDCODE, TDKEY, TDVALUE, status, userid  from <tablename>).

Comment: I had used both the drivers (JDBC type II & JDBC type IV driver), but still the output is false.